# Fast index mapping in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I have the following problem:
Given a matrix A

```
A = [ 1 2 2 3 3 ;
      2 2 2 7 9 ]
```

where the sequence of unique numbers within the matrix is not continuous. In this example

```
unique(A) = [ 1 2 3 7 9 ]. % [ 4 5 6 8 ] are missing
```

I want to compute the same matrix, but using instead a continuous sequence, such that

```
unique(A_new) = [ 1 2 3 4 5 ];
```

I came up with the following solution

```
T = [ unique(A), [ 1:numel(unique(A)) ]' ];

A_new = zeros(size(A));

for i = 1:size(T,1)
  A_new( A == T(i,1) ) = T(i,2);
end
```

This is incredibly slow: the size of the matrix A I have to work with is 200x400x300 and the the number of unique elements within this matrix is 33406.

Any idea on how to speed up the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in your example you want:

```
A_new = [ 1 2 2 3 3 ;
          2 2 2 4 5 ]
```

So just compute a lookup table (`lookup`) such that you can then do:

```
A_new = lookup(A);
```

So in your case, `lookup` would be:

```
[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 4 0 5 ]
```

I'll leave the process for generating that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: looks like lookup is part of Simulink. I don't have Simulink :-(

Comment: @user1384636: I don't mean anything in Simulink.  I mean a variable called `lookup`.

Comment: The variable `lookup` can be generated by `lookup(unique(A))=1:length(unique(A))`

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1 (not recommended)

This should be pretty fast, but it uses more memory:

```
[~, A_new] = max(bsxfun(@eq, A(:).', unique(A(:))));
A_new = reshape(A_new, size(A));
```

**How does this work?**

First `A` is linearized into a vector (`A(:)`). Also, a vector containing the unique values of `A` is computed (`unique(A(:))`). From those two vectors a matrix is generated (with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)) in which each entry of `A` is compared to each of the unique values. That way, for each entry of `A` we know if it equals the *first* unique value, or the *second* unique value, etc. For the `A` given in your question, that matrix is

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

So for example, the value `1` in entry (2,3) indicates that the third value of `A(:)` equals the *second* unique value of `A` (namely `2`). The `1` in the lower-right entry (5,10) indicates that the tenth value of `A(:)` is the *fifth* unique value of `A` (which is `9`).

Now the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) is used to extract the row position of the `1` value in each columnn (i.e. to obtain the numbers indicating "*second*", "*fifth*" etc in the above example)). These are the desired results. It only remains to [`reshape`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) them into the shape of `A`.

### Approach 2 (recommended)

The third output of [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) does what you want:

```
[~, ~, labels] = unique(A);
A_new = reshape(labels, size(A));
```

Comment: This time with detailed explanation _à la_ @rayryeng :-)

Comment: This seems awfully heavyweight compared to my answer.  Are we solving the same problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't know... you left it unsolved, actually :-P

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree that your solution is lighter, and much more memory-efficient

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ... unless `A` contains an exceedingly large value, that is. But in that case a `sparse` matrix `lookup` could be used

Comment: @user1384636 See new approach 2 in my answer